# OutofMemory error for spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job running in Hortonworks cluster .
I am running it in cluster mode through yarn , the job is shown as running in UI , but it is having the below exception in driver logs

```
Exception in thread "JobGenerator" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by specifying driver-memory in spark-submit command.because the memory issue was in driver